# Why does every 4k wallpaper get lower resolution after logging in?

Tags: nvidia, desktop-background, display-resolution, 4k-monitor

So I have a 4k screen, and when I set a 4k wallpaper it seems to be a lower resolution Full HD maybe. This is especially noticeable when I come to the login screen it's crystal clear 4k, and then after I log in it is visibly worse.

Any ideas or experiences regarding this?

Comment: No one knows huh?

Comment: no dude, no one.

Comment: give up already